# The confusion about Global object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am beginner at JavaScript and I am trying to understand the Global window object in JavaScript. So, is it ok if I just imagine that any code that I write in the console like `var text = "Hello"; console.log(text)` is put inside window object like this `Window{var text = "Hello"; console.log(this.text)} with this referencing window object`. Is it ok if I consider it like that or it is not correct? Thank you

Comment: More about Global Object you can read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object

Comment: Just [enable strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and don't let the global object worry you.

Comment: And javascript may run in different environments. So don't forget that your question is only valid in browsers

Comment: Enable strict mode. About your sentence, no, you can't imagine about `var text` as something that always belongs to `window`. If you want to, play around with this: https://jsfiddle.net/rpkgewz3/

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı while the `window` object only exists in browsers, JavaScript has a global object in all environments and this behavior is the same. @mirzhal Yes you can treat top level declarations as being properties of global scope but you're better off taking @Quentin's advice

Comment: @briosheje jsfiddle wraps the code in an onload. Hence `console.log(window.a)` shows undefined. If you switch the load type to "No wrap" it will print 10.

Comment: @AntonHolmberg I Know, that's to prove that there is a very wide scenario about how `window` is filled. It largely depends on the script environment and, if it's within a browser, whether it's in the head or in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not pretty safe to make assumptions about the `global` object or the default `this` context, as it can vary from one javascript runtime to another, and some features like [the strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) also change this behavior.

Keep in mind that javascript not only runs in the browser -and global in node.js for instance does not work as in the browser-, and that there are a lot of different browser implementations out there.

Also, while `var` does write to global by default in some environments, `const` and `let` doesn't.

In node, functions called freely with no previous reference won't call them from `global`, but will fail instead. This heavily affects also front-end code since much of javascript for the browser nowadays is pre-compiled in a node environment via webpack etc.

So, succintly: is usually difficult to assume things about `global`, `window` and default `this` bindings and get them right. **It is probably safer to assume that you don't have a default global object available and always refer `window` explicitly**, as:

**config.js**

```
window.config = {foo: 'bar'}

window.someGlobalFunction = function() {...}
```

**user.js**

```
// do:
const elen = new User(window.config);
window.someGlobalFunction();

// don't
const elen = new User(config);
someGlobalFunction();
```

Comment: That clientside code gets precompiled *in Node* does not mean that it gets *run on Node*. That part could be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

> "is it ok to use the global object?"

Of course it is. If you know about the pitfalls and use the global object *by purpose* and not *by accident*.

```
 (function() {
    name = 12; // Note: This *is* a global variable
    console.log(typeof name); // string. WTF
 })();
```

The pitfalls are:

1) All undeclared (!) variables, and global variables declared with `var` automatically get part of the global object. That is bad, as that happens without any good reason, so you should avoid that (use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), and [`let` and `const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2)).

2) All scripts you run do have the same global object, so *properties can collide*. Thats what happens in the example above, `name` collides with the global `window.name` getter / setter pair that casts the number to a string. So if you set properties in the global object, make sure that the name is only used by you, and not by others (the browser, libraries, other codepieces you wrote ...)

If you know about these pitfalls and avoid them, you can and should use the global object *by purpose*, if, and only if, you plan to share a certain function / variable between different scripts on the page, so if it should really be *globally accessible*.

```
 let private = 1;  
  window.shared = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any function or variable can be accessed from the window object example:

```
var foo = "foobar";
foo === window.foo; // Returns: true


function greeting() {
   console.log("Hi!");
}

window.greeting(); // It is the same as the normal invoking: greeting();
```

Comment: C, can I imagine that the above code is like Window{var foo = "foobar";
function greeting() {
   console.log("Hi!");
}

greeting(); } just imagine Window object is like huge sack to which any code we write is put. Is that ok?